# Only one of my jQuery Dialog's is showing. How do I make them all show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web, dialog

I have created 4 jQuery Dialog's like below shows:

```
    <div id="addCustomer" title="Add Customer">
    <h2>Add Customer</h2>
    <label>Customer Name: </label><input type="text" name ="customerName" id="addCustomerName"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="addCustomerBtn" /><br/>
    <a href="#" id="close">Close</a>
</div>
<div id="editCustomer" title="Edit Customer">
    <h2>Edit Customer</h2>
    <label>Customer Name: </label><input type="text" name="editCustomerName" id="editCustomerName"/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="editCustomerbtn"/> <br/>
    <a href="#" id="editClose">Close</a>
</div>
<div id="deleteCustomer" title="Delete Customer">
    <h2>Delete Customer</h2>
    <label>Are you sure you want to delete this customer?</label><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Yes" id="confirmDeleteCustomer"/> <input type="button" value="No" id="cancelDeleteCustomer"/>
</div>
<div id="addDevice" title="Add Device">
    <h2>Add Device</h2>
    <label>Device Id:   </label><input type="text" name="addDeviceId" id="addDeviceId"/><br/><br/>
    <label>Version:     </label><input type="text" name ="addDeviceVersion" id="addDeviceVersion"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="addDeviceBtn"/> <br/> 
    <a href="#" id="addDeviceClose">Close</a>
</div>
```

And I have set them to be hidden to begin with in the page start like this:

```
$("#addCustomer").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true
    });
    $("#deleteCustomer").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true
    });
    $("#addDevice").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true
    });
    $("#editCustomer").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true
    });
```

Now I am trying to call each from an option on a context menu, as below demonstrates, but when I try, the first dialog box I choose to open, opens fine, but once that is closed, no dialog box will open again on the page.

```
if (e.item.name == "itmAddCustomer") {
        $(function() {
            $("#addCustomer").dialog("open");            
        });            
    }
```

I have only shown one example of the menu buttons here, but you get the gist.

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this?

Cheers

**UPDATE:** Here is the code for the context menu in relation to the answer below:

```
<div id="popupMenu" style="z-index:19998;display:none;">
        <div class="dxm-popupMain dxm-shadow dxm-popup">
            <ul class="dx dxm-noImages dxm-gutter">
                <li class="dxm-item"><div class="dxm-content dxm-hasText">
                    Expand
                </div><b class="dx-clear"></b></li><li class="dxm-spacing"></li><li class="dxm-item"><div class="dxm-content dxm-hasText">
                    Enable
                </div><b class="dx-clear"></b></li><li class="dxm-spacing"></li><li class="dxm-item"><div class="dxm-content dxm-hasText">
                    Add Customer
                </div><b class="dx-clear"></b></li><li class="dxm-spacing"></li><li class="dxm-item"><div class="dxm-content dxm-hasText">
                    Edit Customer
                </div><b class="dx-clear"></b></li><li class="dxm-spacing"></li><li class="dxm-item"><div class="dxm-content dxm-hasText">
                    Delete Customer
                </div><b class="dx-clear"></b></li><li class="dxm-spacing"></li><li class="dxm-item"><div class="dxm-content dxm-hasText">
                    Add Device
                </div><b class="dx-clear"></b></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any javascript error on your browser console ? Could you put all of this in a jsFiddle ?

Comment: Why dont you just put all the selectors together?

Comment: have you tried to destroy the dialogue before creating new one?
Inside close event, something like $(this.)dialogue("destroy");

Comment: @pistache yes indeed I do. The js error is Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)} has no method 'curCSS'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that to fix this issue, All I needed to do was update from jQuery-Ui 1.8.11 to jQuery-ui 1.9.0, and all the issues just disappeared.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is something that could fit your needs . [SqlFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eawtD/2/)

They are some conventions (which might be removed, it just makes code shorter) :

Each dialog div has a `.dialog` class (so all dialogs are closed when the `select` value changes)

Each option value of the select = `item` + corresponding dialog div's id.

I used a `select` , not sure what's your

> option on a context menu

HTML part :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<select id ="actionChooser">
    <option value ="">-choisir-</option>
    <option value="itemaddCustomer">Add</option>
    <option value="itemeditCustomer">Edit</option>
    <option value="itemdeleteCustomer">Delete</option>
    <option value="itemaddDevice">Add device</option>
</select>

<div id="addCustomer" class="dialog" title="Add Customer">
    <h2>Add Customer</h2>
    <label>Customer Name: </label><input type="text" name ="customerName" id="addCustomerName"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="addCustomerBtn" /><br/>
</div>

<div id="editCustomer"  class="dialog" title="Edit Customer">
    <h2>Edit Customer</h2>
    <label>Customer Name: </label><input type="text" name="editCustomerName" id="editCustomerName"/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="editCustomerbtn"/> <br/>
</div>
<div id="deleteCustomer"  class="dialog" title="Delete Customer">
    <h2>Delete Customer</h2>
    <label>Are you sure you want to delete this customer?</label><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Yes" id="confirmDeleteCustomer"/> <input type="button" value="No" id="cancelDeleteCustomer"/>
</div>
<div id="addDevice"  class="dialog" title="Add Device">
    <h2>Add Device</h2>
    <label>Device Id:   </label><input type="text" name="addDeviceId" id="addDeviceId"/><br/><br/>
    <label>Version:     </label><input type="text" name ="addDeviceVersion" id="addDeviceVersion"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="addDeviceBtn"/> <br/> 
</div> ​​​​​​​
```

JQuery part

```
$("#actionChooser").change(function(e) {
    $('.dialog').dialog('close');
    var val = '#'+$(this).val().replace('item', '');

    $(val).dialog('open'); 
});

   $("#addCustomer, #deleteCustomer, #addDevice, #editCustomer").dialog({// or just $('.dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: true
});
```

**EDIT**

with your given html (I modified the "dialogs" part) : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eawtD/3/)

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="popupMenu" style="z-index:19998;">
        <div class="dxm-popupMain dxm-shadow dxm-popup">
            <ul class="dx dxm-noImages dxm-gutter">
                <li class="dxm-item"><div class="dxm-content dxm-hasText">
                    Expand
                </div><b class="dx-clear"></b></li><li class="dxm-spacing"></li><li class="dxm-item"><div class="dxm-content dxm-hasText">
                    Enable
                </div><b class="dx-clear"></b></li><li class="dxm-spacing"></li><li class="dxm-item"><div class="dxm-content dxm-hasText">
                    Add Customer
                </div><b class="dx-clear"></b></li><li class="dxm-spacing"></li><li class="dxm-item"><div class="dxm-content dxm-hasText">
                    Edit Customer
                </div><b class="dx-clear"></b></li><li class="dxm-spacing"></li><li class="dxm-item"><div class="dxm-content dxm-hasText">
                    Delete Customer
                </div><b class="dx-clear"></b></li><li class="dxm-spacing"></li><li class="dxm-item"><div class="dxm-content dxm-hasText">
                    Add Device
                </div><b class="dx-clear"></b></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<hr/>
<div id="addCustomer" class="dialog" title="Add Customer">
    <h2>Add Customer</h2>
    <label>Customer Name: </label><input type="text" name ="customerName" id="addCustomerName"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="addCustomerBtn" /><br/>

</div>
<div id="editCustomer" class="dialog" title="Edit Customer">
    <h2>Edit Customer</h2>
    <label>Customer Name: </label><input type="text" name="editCustomerName" id="editCustomerName"/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="editCustomerbtn"/> <br/>

</div>
<div id="deleteCustomer" class="dialog" title="Delete Customer">
    <h2>Delete Customer</h2>
    <label>Are you sure you want to delete this customer?</label><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Yes" id="confirmDeleteCustomer"/> <input type="button" value="No" id="cancelDeleteCustomer"/>
</div>
<div id="addDevice" class="dialog" title="Add Device">
    <h2>Add Device</h2>
    <label>Device Id:   </label><input type="text" name="addDeviceId" id="addDeviceId"/><br/><br/>
    <label>Version:     </label><input type="text" name ="addDeviceVersion" id="addDeviceVersion"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="addDeviceBtn"/> <br/> 

</div>
```

jQuery Part

```
$('div .dxm-content').click(function() {
    $('.dialog').dialog('close');
    var popupText = $.trim($(this).html());
    var dialogId;
    if (popupText.length > 0) {
        switch(popupText) {
            case 'Edit Customer' : dialogId = 'editCustomer';
            break;
            case 'Delete Customer' : dialogId= 'deleteCustomer'; 
            break;
            case 'Add Device' : dialogId = 'addDevice';
            break;
            case 'Add Customer': dialogId = 'addCustomer';
            break;
            default : dialogId='';
            break;
        }
        if (dialogId != '') {
            $('#'+ dialogId).dialog('open');
        }
    }
});

$('.dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true
    });
```

​

Comment: This looks along the right lines. The context menu is a menu that apears on a right click of a node in a treeview. I am using DevExpress for the treeview and context menu (DevExpress PopupMenu) Don't know how I would change it to handle the context menu items rather than the select.

Comment: I would paste the generated HTML into the question, but it is too long, so instead, I'll paste the context menu HTML into the question for you :)

Comment: Thank you. I managed to fix the issue I was having by updating the version of jQuery UI to the latest version. I also had a double reference to jQuery itself, and removing that seemed to have helped.